# Lebesgue Integrability Questions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

1. If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is integrable, I want to show $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(n^ax+cos(n))$ converges for a.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a>1$
2. I want to show $\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow 1} \int |g(x)(f(x)-f(tx))| dx = 0$ given $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $g \in L_{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) $.

Attempt:
I can show that $\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow 1} \int |g(x)(f(x)-f(tx))| dx \le ||g||_{\infty}\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow 1} \int |(f(x)-f(tx))| dx$ and if I simply evaluate the limit, I get $||g||_{\infty} \int|f(x)-f(x))| dx = 0$. Is this enough?

Answer (score 2):

For 1., use the transformation $t=n^ax+\cos n$ with the integral $\int |f(n^ax+\cos n)| dx = \frac{1}{n^a} \int |f|$. Tonelli gives $\int \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |f(n^ax+\cos n)| dx =\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int |f(n^ax+\cos n)| dx  = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n^a} \int |f| < \infty$. It follows that $ x \mapsto \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |f(n^ax+\cos n)|$ is finite a.e., from which the desired result follows.

For 2., you already have observed that $\int |g(x)(f(x)-f(tx))| dx \le \|g\|_\infty \int |f(x)-f(tx)| dx$. Let $f_t(x) = f(tx)$, then to finish, you need to show that the map $ t \mapsto f_t$ is continuous at $t=1$.

As an aside, note that $\int f_t = \frac{1}{t} \int f$.

If $g \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ (continuous functions with compact support), then a uniform continuity argument shows that $\lim_{t \to 1}\|g - g_t\|_1 = 0$. Since $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, if $ \epsilon >0$ we can find $g \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\|f-g\|_1 < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Then we have the estimate 
\begin{eqnarray}
\|f-f_t\|_1 &\le& \|f-g\|_1 + \|g-g_t\|_1 + \|f_t-g_t\|_1\\
&=& (1+\frac{1}{t}) \|f-g\|_1 + \|g-g_t\|_1 \\
&\le& (1+\frac{1}{t}) \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \|g-g_t\|_1
\end{eqnarray}
Consequently, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that if $|1-t| < \delta$, then $\|f-f_t\|_1 < \epsilon$. Hence $ t \mapsto f_t$ is continuous at $t=1$.

Comment: For 1, I understand that $|f|$ is integrable so $\int |f| < \infty$, but why does this imply that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n^a} \int |f|$ need be finite? Doesnt The integral depends on $n$ so we can factor it out and claim convergence.

For 2, the original integral is for $|f(x) - f(tx)|$ as opposed to $||f(x) - f(tx)||$. The 1-norm is the sum of absolute value terms so does this still work?

Comment: I guess my question for 2 really boils down do how do $\int |f(x)-f(tx)|$ and $\int ||f(x) - f(tx)||_1$ relate?

Comment: For 1, $\int|f|$ is a constant, and the sum is known to converge for $a>1$. (The point is that by change of variables, the dependence on $n$ is moved outside the integral.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question for 2. $\|f-f_t\|_1 = \int |f(x)-f(tx)| dx$. I'm not integrating the norm anywhere?

Comment: Oh I see but I believe that the assumption you make about a continuous $g$ with compact support approximating $f$ only works for $L_p$ norms for $1 < p < \infty$.

Comment: It works for $p=1$. In fact, $L^1$ can be defined as the completion of the integrable continuous functions with the $L^1$ norm, and the continuous functions with compact support are dense in the integrable continuous functions (with the $L^1$ norm).